If $n$ is irrational, then $n^n$ is not necessarily irrational?
It seemed to me that $n^n$ had to be irrational if $n$ is irrational, because I couldn't find any examples that gave a rational number. I also couldn't find any sources about this specific expression, so I gave it a go.
I decided to employ the use of a recurrence relation in order to prove it's rationality. The sequence I defined is:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n^{-x_n},$$
where the first term, $x_0$ is $> 0$ to make sure the argument stays well defined. This sequence is not monotonic as it alternates between two values that seem to converge to $1$. But this sequence can be split into two, for every other number, and those sub-sequences are monotonic. These are $x_{2n+1}$ (decreasing) and $x_{2n+2}$ (increasing). Now returning to the original relation, we know that it stays above $0$ as $x_0 > 0$, so the base $x_n$ is always positive. By then placing an upper bound, we can conclude that the sequence is convergent and solve using the limit. The upper bound is simply the maximum of $x^{-x}$, as it would be the most the sequence could reach. This can be calculated by finding when the derivative is equal to $0$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-x}]=-\frac{1}{(x^x)^2}\times\frac{d}{dx}[x^x]$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-x}]=-\frac{x^x(1+\ln(x))}{(x^x)^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-x}]=-\frac{1+\ln(x)}{x^x}$$
Now solving for when it is equal to $0$:
$$-\frac{1+\ln(x)}{x^x}=0$$
$$1+\ln(x)=0$$
$$x=e^{-1}$$
Plugging into $x^{-x}$:
$$= (e^{-1})^{(e^{-1})}$$
$$= e^{\frac{1}{e}}$$
$$\approx 1.445$$
Now that it's convergence is verified, we can now solve using the limit ($L$ represents the limit):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^{-x_n}$$
$$L=L^{-L}$$
$$L^{-(1+L)}=1$$
$$L=1,-1$$
We obtain two answers for $L$, however since the sequence is strictly positive then $1$ is the only answer.
After solving this sequence, we get $1$, a rational number. This contradicts my initial belief that $n^n$ is irrational if $n$ is irrational. The reason for this is the way the recurrence relation is structured. $x_2$ will always be irrational as shown:
$$x_2=(x_0^{-x_0})^{-(x_0^{-x_0})}$$
$$x_2=x_0^{x_0^{1-x_0}}$$
Since $x_0>0$, then $1-x_0$ will be negative, resulting in $x_2=x_0^{(\frac{1}{x_0^{x_0-1}})}$. We know that the $n$th root of $n$ is irrational, and since $x_0^{x_0-1}>x_0$, then $x_2$ must be irrational. Every term onwards follows $n^{-n}$. Since we only care about the rationality, this can be adapted to $n^n$, as the reciprocal of an irrational number is irrational. If we assumed the initial statement to be true, that $n^n$ is irrational if $n$ is irrational, then every term in the sequence after $x_2$ would be irrational, meaning that it would converge to an irrational number. This contradicts the solution found beforehand that it converges to $1$, a rational number, therefore $n^n$ is not necessarily irrational if $n$ is irrational.
What I would like to know is if there are any holes in my logic, or if there is something I did wrong. And if I am correct, what are some irrational numbers $n$ of which $n^n$ is rational?

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine. $\ \ $

Please search for answers before posting questions. This question has already been asked and answered many times.

Sorry about that. Where would I be able to check my proof?

$x^x=2$ has a solution by the intermediate value theorem (observe $1^1=1$ and $2^2=4$). I claim $x$ is irrational, so is a counter-example.
For this suppose $x=p/q$ for some coprime natural numbers $p$ and $q$. Then $(p/q)^p=2^q$, i.e., $p^p=2^qq^p$. Since $p^p$ is even, $p$ must be even. But then $q$ must be odd since $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Now $p^p$ contains an even number of $2$'s in the prime factorization but $2^qq^p$ contains an odd number, so there is a contradiction.

Also, if you want an explicit form for this irrational number, you can get it using the Lambert W function: so the real solution of $x^x = 2$ is $e^{W(\log 2)}$, which is your required counterexample.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

@Anon Yes, the solution is $e^{W(\log 2)}$, but that not the important point. The question is about finding an irrational number, and finding the explicit formula doesn't help to prove the number is irrational. Actually, I'd say it would be harder to prove it if the explicit formula is given that if one uses that $x^x=2$.
